# Mail - server name issues?

Tags: email, exim

I asked some time ago a question [Send emails with a custom From: field](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171515/send-emails-with-a-custom-from-field)
However, still can't get exim4 running. It does send emails, but it is unable to receive any. I'm quite sure this might be because of mail server name and MX configuration.

In my control panel I can set Preference, TTL, and Mail Server values for MX. I leave two first ones as default (0, 6400), and the Mail Server I set to "url.com" (I substituted my domain name with "url" name).

But when I send an email to myself, I get:

```
Unroutable address
```

in the main log.
When I run from my linux console " host -t mx url.com" I get:

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

It seems like my MX had no effect at all? What can I do to get it work?

I am very noobie in the subject and even not sure what does "Mail server" refer to? Is it the name that I get by command "host", or maybe "host -f", or maybe "host -i", or maybe even something else? I'm really confused. :/

Here's /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf content:

```
# /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf
#
# Edit this file and /etc/mailname by hand and execute update-exim4.conf
# yourself or use 'dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config'
#
# Please note that this is _not_ a dpkg-conffile and that automatic changes
# to this file might happen. The code handling this will honor your local
# changes, so this is usually fine, but will break local schemes that mess
# around with multiple versions of the file.
#
# update-exim4.conf uses this file to determine variable values to generate
# exim configuration macros for the configuration file.
#
# Most settings found in here do have corresponding questions in the
# Debconf configuration, but not all of them.
#
# This is a Debian specific file

dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='url.com; mail.url.com; url; localhost;  localhost.localdomain'
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1; my_ip'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost=''
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='true'
dc_hide_mailname=''
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='maildir_home'
```

For any case, I substituted my domain with url and ip with my_ip.

And /etc/email-addresses is very short:

```
root: contact@url.com
```

And /etc/mailname

```
url.com
```

**Update:** When I do from Windows:

```
nslookup -type=mx url.com
```

I get something like:

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  probably_my_internet_provider's_gate_ip

Non-authoritative answer
url.com  MX preference = 0, mail exchanger = url.com
```

**Update 2:**
Now I really am confused. I tried to run "dig mx url.com" and "host -t mx url.com" from **the other mail linux server (not mine)**, and it seems to be ok, e.g. the last one results in:

```
url.com mail is handled by 0 url.com
```

But where are my e-mails then?? I can't see in ~/Maildir anything. And when I run "mail" I get msg that there's "No mail for root". So does it work, or it doesn't... or what?

**Update 3: IS THIS A ROUTING PROBLEM?**
Now I can see that when I'm trying to send an e-mail from contact@url.com, it fails with the following message:

"Unroutable adress"

concerning the contact@url.com address (so it's not the target "TO" one, but the "FROM" one). It didn't happen before (say a month ago), so I probably messed up some config. :/

When I do, as suggested by some net tutorial:

```
exim4 -d -bt mail
```

I get *a lot of* different "routers" (I'm not even sure if I do understand them properly, though I've read a section in the exim4 documumentation), specifically:

- hubbed_hosts router ("router skipped: domains mismatch")
- dnslookup_relay_to_domains router ("router skipped: domains mismatch")
- dnslookup router ("router skipped: domains mismatch")
- real_local router ("router skipped: prefix mismatch")
- system_aliases router ("system_aliases router declined for mail@url.com")
- userforward router ("router skipped: file check")
- procmail router ("router skipped: file check")
- maildrop router ("router skipped: file check")
- lowuid_aliases router ("router skipped: condition failure")
- local_user router (see below):

The last one ends with quite a long response:

```
--------> local_user router <--------
local_part=mail domain=url.com
checking domains
cached yes match for +local_domains
cached lookup data = NULL
url.com in "+local_domains"? yes (matched "+local_domains" - cached)
checking local_parts
mail in "! root"? yes (end of list)
checking for local user
seeking password data for user "mail": using cached result
getpwnam() succeeded uid=8 gid=8
R: local_user for mail@url.com
calling local_user router
local_user router called for mail@url.com
  domain = url.com
set transport maildir_home
    queued for maildir_home transport: local_part = mail
domain = url.com
  errors_to=NULL
  domain_data=NULL localpart_data=NULL
routed by local_user router
  envelope to: mail@url.com
  transport: maildir_home
  mail@url.com
  router = local_user, transport = maildir_home
search_tidyup called
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Exim pid=31821 terminating with rc=0 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

I wonder now, why does it use "mail@url.com", not "contact@url.com" here? Is this something normal?

And foremost: ***Which ROUTER is the one I should be interested in my case, that is when I'm attempting to send a message with (now) a "mail" command from the command line to the foreign e-mail address?***

Comment: You have to show your config at least. Sure you have to clear out all sensible information from it.

Comment: I updated post.

Comment: Can you post the output of the command ```dig -t mx url.com +trace```?

Comment: What is the output of: `ping -c4 mail.yoururl.com`?

Comment: Yes, when run from my linux server, I get nothing, but when from other linux server, I got number of server names, and correctly resolving the name, ending with my DNS server name, and finally with my MX record I set there.

Comment: I don't have subdomain mail.url.com, so no response, but it responds on url.com (without a subdomain). But in MX I have url.com, not mail.url.com.

Comment: Does `url.com` have an A record, that points to the system running exim? Also ensure that the system can resolve DNS requests, your first "host -t mx url.com" giving a timeout makes me wonder whether it can resolve anything.

Comment: Yes, Record A points to the ip of the server. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Thanks for all your suggestions. The problem was connected to Name Servers, and after all they now correctly resolve names.